# SQL for Splitting Names - Some with Middle Initial, Some Without

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm fairly new to SQL, I'm actually just building a small database in Access right now although if there is necessary functionality that Access can't do I'll remake the tables in SQL Server.

Here's my situation, I have a list of names that come from a data dump from a third party. In our database I need to be able to compare first and last names in separate columns.

I've been trying to use InStr, Left and Right - but am getting hung up with weird results

```
Left([NewClaims]![Claimant Full Name],InStr([NewClaims]![Claimant Full Name],",")-1) AS LastName, 
Right([NewClaims]![Claimant Full Name],InStr([NewClaims]![Claimant Full Name], ", ")+2) AS FirstName,
```

On some names it works perfectly

```
West, Krystal --becomes--> LastName = West, FirstName= Krystal
```

On other names, similar in formant it doesn't work

```
Dalton, Kathy ----> LastName = Dalton, First Name = ON, KATHY
```

On Names with middle initials I get

```
Earles, Barbara A. ----> LastName = Earles, FirstName= ARBARA A. (one missing letter)
```

OR

```
Beard, Chekitha G. ----> LastName = Beard, FirstName= KITHA G. (three missing letters)
```

I'm frustrated. Can anyone offer another idea on how to make this work? I seem to have the last name down, but I can't get the first name to be consistently correct.

Comment: I can offer you the advice to go directly to SQL Server.  It is a more powerful database.

Comment: What would you like to happen if the row had Schrank, Mary Ann and Ann was part of the first name? Her Middle Name? In other words how well do you know your data? If there is a middle "name" is it always an innitial followed by a period.

Comment: Access Sql and Sql Server T-Sql are pretty different. You should start with the one you will end up using.

Comment: I think the best option is making multiple columns

Answer (score 2):

Try this. But I'm assuming that there's always a comma that separates last name from first name.

```
select
    txt,
    LastName = left(txt,charindex(',',txt)-1),
    FirstName = ltrim(right(txt,len(txt)-charindex(',',txt)))
from (
    select 'West, Krystal' as txt union all
    select 'Dalton, Kathy' union all
    select 'Earles, Barbara A.' union all
    select 'Beard, Chekitha G.'
) x
```

Your mistake was that when using `right` to extract first name, you didn't take the length of the string under consideration.